# Can you open your app from the browser without any user prompt?

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, express, next.js

So I have setup an app that works both for android and ios and setup the according app link and universal link. Now I want to be able to when the user opens a specific site to redirect them from the browser to the app. All the mobile part is done and I am specifically working on the browser / server part where the server sends a 301 redirect response to the browser and the browser should be able to tell:

- Is the app installed or not?
- Open the app or continue with the web experience

I have done quite a bit of research and the only thing I somewhat found could solve my problem was onelink.to but they only offer universal app download links, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. Does anybody have an idea or hint where or what I could be doing or looking else for?

Just to make it absoluetly clear, the intended behaviour should be that the browser should automatically open up the app when the server sends a redirect with the domain name of the app.

Comment: You say you have set up app link and universal link for your app. That's exactly the thing that does what you are describing, so I'm not sure what it is that you exactly want

Comment: The issue is when I send a redirect response to the client, it does not work. When I add a button, that fires up the redirect, then it works. Do you understand what I mean? @Ivo

Comment: ah okay. I don't know how that exactly works. Hopefully someone can help you out

Comment: How is the user interaction with the webapp that causes the server to send a redirect?  For many actions the system requires an explicit user interaction (like clicks or similar) to be executed. Might be the case here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `user gesture` before opening a deep link. It is unlikely to work consistently otherwise. A well known example is when invoking an app after an OAuth login redirect. My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917296/oauth-redirect-with-an-app-link-not-working-occasionally/71929739) has some further info on this topic.

Therefore put some user experience around it, with messages like `Click here to open the app`, or `Continue on the web`. This is a pretty standard user experience and keeps the user informed.

Comment: That's the notion I was starting to get after countless experiments but thank you for the answer. Is there maybe a resource where these kinds of things are defined? @Gary Archer

Comment: It's not very documented but my previous answer links has some links to related threads.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a link to a redirect is the user firing off a HTTP request manually. You can automate this by using the following javascript code on the webpage that you want to automatically open the app for:

```js
const deepLink = 'yourapp://path/to/content';
window.location.href = deepLink;

// If the app is not installed, we can set a timeout to redirect somewhere else.
setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = 'https://yourappwebsite.com';
}, 2000);
```

If you want the current page to be stored in the session history, you can use `window.location.replace()` instead.

[MDN documentation for `location.href`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

Comment: I tried doing it this way, but it still didn't work unfortunately. Do you have any more ideas perhaps? @Titulum

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open('deep-link', '_blank')`;

Try with and without the second parameter. Also, make sure your intent-filters are properly set in your app's manifest.

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Questioner is asking if it is possible to do it without any user prompt. Answer is no. User action is required for example button click.

Comment: Please share relevant documentation.